# Marqueeing large bodies of text without blank space

Tags: html, css, loops, marquee

For an art exhibition, I'm trying to utilize a locally hosted web page to infinitely scroll information about the pieces near it.

So far I've come up with the idea of using a vertical marquee set to a slow speed so people can read it.  On mouse-over, it stops, then starts when the mouse leaves the space.

(IDEALLY it would allow the user to scroll up and down, and then at input timeout it resumes marqueeing.  That's prob #2 though)

Prob #1 is the Marquee waits until the last line clears the top before starting the loop again at the bottom.  For a page on slow marquee repeat, that means the page is entirely clear of text for a long time until it begins to loop again.

**Prob#1**
How do I get a Marquee to loop immediately after the last line?

**Prob#2**
How do I get the text to be momentarily scrollable until an interaction timeout?

Right now I'm more concerned about #1

**RESOURCES:**

I've been using the basic marqueeing tool with code found here
http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/stop_marquee.cfm

and I've been looking into better code available here, but it still has the same blank stretch of space before loop problem
http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/comment-page-3/

Comment: <marquee> still exists?

Comment: I understand it's not a good option for webpages, but for a gallery setting it keeps the screen moving and inviting.  Needs no more than a minute's worth of attention

Comment: This is usually best achieved with a bit of jQuery, however I answered a SO question on a CSS-only implementation of this a little earlier. The thread can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36565114/5580153

There's a working fiddle in my answer there.

While I'd still recommend finding a script for it like @Rebule said, this option might still give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marquee cant loop, until the whole sentence or text, goes out of view. The best option is jquery scroller. You can check in this site. http://perekhid.te.ua

Look here:

http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/example/endless/